# Advanced searching form

Tags: forms

I am trying to create an advanced searching page on front-end page for users. I have been trying to find but it's not easy to find some tutorial or sample source.

I have found that It is possible to put some filters on admin panel. I am looking for just like this for front-end for users.

[See this tutorial for admin panel](http://pippinsplugins.com/post-list-filters-for-custom-taxonomies-in-manage-posts/)

I need to create like this on front-end for users. this is custom post-type searching.
Any tips? tutorial, sample codes?

Thanks for your time and good weekend ;)

Comment: Please note that asking for someone else to perform research for you is not considered a good question. List the things you did find, how you tried to apply them to your needs and what are specific challenges you have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WP Advanced Search](http://wpadvancedsearch.com/) is exactly what you're looking for. They have a very good documentation.